# Crystal Report section details doesn't create columns

Tags: crystal-reports

I want to print data with two columns in crystal report. For example:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdSvN.png)

But the problem is, I cannot create columns in crystal report. I followed the instructions like *Right Click in Section Details then tick the Format Multiple Columns checkbox then adjust the Gap and detail size in Layout Tab.*    However, only 1 column has been created.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qgHc.png)

I am using the Crystal Report built in in Visual Basic.Net 2008. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Probably due to page margins, page size, detail width and gap, the content can't fit as 2 columns.

Comment: Actually I've played with the detail width and gap size, but still the same output. How to adjust the page margins and page size in crystal report?

Answer (score 0):

Use File, Page Setup to adjust those aspects.

Answer (score 0):

Another suspect is that you never actually previewed the report.
The multi-column layout is rendered during Preview.
So you must actually run the report.

Comment: I previewed the report and run the system to see the actual output of the report but still the same problem.